# ZendFramework - How to wrap my label as well inside by my HtmlTag decorator's tag

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I need to put some form elements in a table. 
I am having the issue, that my HtmlTag decorator wraps only my inputfield and not the label, even if I change the order of adding my decorators.
The label is outstanding of the  tag. Any suggestions?

```
                    $questionElement->addDecorators(array(
                    array( 'HtmlTag',   array( 'tag'=>'tr' ) ),
                    array( 'Label',     array( 'tag'=>'td' ) ),
                ));
```

Comment: Got this solved now by adding 'placedment'=>'prepend' to the label. because my code was in a loop I think the label of the previous element was the one I was complaining about.

Comment: please post the complete source code in the answer and mark it as right. It will help others who read this question. Thanks.

Comment: The complete source is not needed, but I figured out that the loop was not the mistake. The problem here was that I had to alias the decorators. The default names seem to be added in a default order, at least in my set up, so I had no choice in reordering them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wrote a [blog post](http://blog.ashurex.com/2011/07/13/adding-html-tags-zend-form-element/) about this the other day. 
For the purposes of styling I had the need to put an opening  at the beginning of one element, and a closing  tag at the end of another. The Zend Framework guides don't do a great job of detailing this.

On the element you want to add the opening div tag you would do the following:

```
$open_element->addDecorator(array(
    array('openDiv' =>'HtmlTag'),
    array('tag' => 'div', 'openOnly' => true)
));
```

On the second element, you'll want to add the closing tags:

```
$close_element->addDecorator(array(
    array('closeDiv' =>'HtmlTag'),
    array('tag' => 'div', 'closeOnly' => true)
));
```